# How to bind an event to Tabbing Off an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following for a dropdown:

```
/* recurse through dropdown menus */
$('.dropdown').each(function() {
    /* track elements: menu, parent */
    var dropdown = $(this);
    var menu = dropdown.next('div.dropdown-menu'), parent = dropdown.parent();
    /* function that shows THIS menu */
    var showMenu = function() {
        hideMenu();
        showingDropdown = dropdown.addClass('dropdown-active');
        showingMenu = menu.show();
        showingParent = parent;
    };
    /* function to show menu when clicked */
    dropdown.bind('click',function(e) {
        if(e) e.stopPropagation();
        if(e) e.preventDefault();
        showMenu();
    });
    /* function to show menu when someone tabs to the box */
    dropdown.bind('focus',function() {
        showMenu();
    });
});

/* hide when clicked outside */
$(document.body).bind('click',function(e) {
    if(showingParent) {
        var parentElement = showingParent[0];
        if(!$.contains(parentElement,e.target) || !parentElement == e.target) {
            hideMenu();
        }
    }
});
```

Notice:

$(document.body).bind('click',function(e) {

The problem is that the dropdown opens on click or when you tab to it. But it only closes on click, not when you tab out.

How can I bind an event to mean "tabbing out" ,losing focus, so the dropdown closes?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could trigger a click outside when you press the tab key. Like this:

```
$('#your_dropdown').bind('keydown', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (keyCode == 9) {  //If it's the tab key
    $("body").click(); //Force a click outside the dropdown, so it forces a close
  } 
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Seriously? There're two events (`blur, focusout`) specifically designed to tell you when an element loses focus, but instead you're trapping keypresses and looking for tabs?

Answer (score 2):

Try the `blur` event, which will be triggered when the control loses focus (i.e., when the user clicks outside the control or uses the keyboard to tab to the next control).

Put something like this just after your existing `focus` binding:

```
dropdown.bind('blur',function() {
  // whatever tests you want
  hideMenu();
});
```

(You shouldn't then need the separate click binding that you're currently using to hide the menu.)

P.S. You might also consider `focusout`, which is similar to `blur` except that it bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for the `onblur` event?

Comment: That doesn't work... $(document.body).bind('click onblur',function(e) {

Comment: @AnApprentice - try `blur` instead of `onblur` (`onblur` is used if you want to say `element.onblur=...`), but note that `blur` doesn't bubble, so you don't want to bind it to the body: bind it to your menu element, or try `focusout`. See my answer.

Comment: Well, this is the JavaScript event.  Given that the events in your code are called `click` and `focus` instead of `onclick` and `onfocus`, it's probably just called `blur`.